# Query update result in huge unexpected number

Tags: php, mysql

I have some problems with my hiscore table. Some players have got a lot of points really fast, more then possible. I post two code below:

The first one is the one I currently use, which cause the problem:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']); 
$set = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['set']); 


if ($set == 1 && isset($_POST['score']))
{
    $score = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['score']); 

    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET totalScore=totalScore + '$score' WHERE username='$name'"); 

    if ($query) 
    {
        echo 'success'; 
    }
    else {
        echo 'error'; 
    }

}
```

I tried to cast the score as an int in the code below, but the update result is a huge number (4294967295) to be set as the totalScore. The totalScore is of type int(25) and I set attribute to unsigned so a player can't end up on the minus side.

Please help
Thanks

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']); 
$set = (int)$_POST['set']; 


if ($set == 1 && isset($_POST['score']))
{
    $score = (int)$_POST['score']; 

    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET totalScore=totalScore + $score WHERE username='$name'"); 

    if ($query) 
    {
        echo 'success'; 
    }
    else {
        echo 'error'; 
    }

}
```

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 3):

if this is the only script that you use to save the score no wonder that people cheated to get high score - in order to prevent it you need to insert some encryption to the parameters, and add some session and time based protections to the script

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are adding a integer onto propably an integer datatype. There is no need of quotes and escaping, if you make sure the input is integer (*which you are already doing*)

```
"UPDATE users SET totalScore=totalScore + $score WHERE username='$name'" LIMIT 1;
```

Only you are updating the query based on the name, You might need to LIMIT the execution.